# How can I query a referenced object for a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am creating a Spring Boot Application and I am using MongoDB with it. I have 2 collections. One called review, the other called book. In a review, there is a reference to the book. What I am trying to do is to write a method that would allow me to search a book name, and get all the reviews on it.

The challenge is to not change the database structure. So, I cannot just make review a field for the book collection.

I tried the following:

Repository:

```
public List<Reviews> findByBooksNameContainsIgnoreCase (String name);
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/reviews/searchbybook")
public List<Reviews> locationReviews(@RequestBody Books book){
        List<Reviews> results= commentRepository.findByBooksNameContainsIgnoreCase(book.getName());
        return results;
    }
```

getName() [function in the class declaration of Books as part of Model]:

```
private String name;

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Example of a Reviews Document:

```
{
      _id: ObjectId('645762e828u3927h393u9293'),
      reviewer: "someone",
      review: "Awesome Book!",
      book: DBRef('books', '645762e828u3927h393u9292)
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: If we can't include the review as a field for the Book collection, then what is the relationship or link of the review with the book to identify the review is linked with book ?

Comment: @MadhawaGunasekara the review has a reference to the book's id

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try the below-suggested approach.

Since you can't modify the db schema you need to first get the bookId related to bookName from Books.

Then we could fetch Reviews based on this bookId from db separately.

**Review Repository**

```
@Query("custom query here")     
public List<Reviews> findAllByBookId(String bookId);
```

**Book Repository**

```
@Query("custom query here")     
public Book findByBookName(String name);
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/reviews/searchbybook")
public List<Reviews> locationReviews(@RequestBody Books book){

        Book fetchedBook = bookRepository.findByBookName(book.getName()).get(); // Fetch Book related to input bookName
        List<Reviews> results= reviewRepository.findAllByBookId(fetchedBook.getId()); //Now fetch list of reviews by using available bookId reference
        return results;
    }
```